# Why are all my numbers overlapped?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, processing.js

```
background(0, 0, 0);
for (var i = 1950; i < 2051; i++) {
    for (var x = 17; x < 411; x +=34) {
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        text(i, x, 81);   
    }
}
```

variable i is just counting from 1950 until it hits 2050 adding by one. VARIABLE x is just making each number be 34 pixels apart. The thing is that it puts ALL the numbers (1950 - 2050) together then goes onto the next pile, 34 pixels away, to do the same!?

https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-midnight-snow/5256320686620672

Comment: Your code is using functions that you haven't shown to the rest of us. How do you expect us to know how to fix it?

Comment: It's because your loop is nested, so you're telling it to draw every number ~11 times.

Comment: Thanks marty, but I have asked this before and they said to nest it?

Comment: I gave you the link to the site!

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to make the numbers be by themselves instead of all being mushed together. Look at the site please.

Comment: @bob Your "site" has even less code shown than it does here.    I'm not sure what the link is supposed to give us...   but if you would like further assistance with the question, please take the time to provide more detailed code, maybe a screenshot of what you are seeing that is going wrong, etc.

Comment: Marty has answered my question. He was smart enough to help. Thanks, Marty!

Comment: Thank the rest of you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your loop is nested, so you're telling it to draw every number ~11 times. It looks like you want something like this instead:

```
background(0, 0, 0);
fill(255, 0, 0);

var x = 0;
for (var i = 1950; i < 2051; i++) {
    text(i, x, 81);
    x += 34;
}
```

Here's an [updated version of your link](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-midnight-snow/6392760308989952).